# Java adjust data type depending on input

Tags: java, types, custom-data-type

I have multiple classes defining different objects (eg. apple, banana, lemon), and multiple processors that transform theses objects (eg apple-processor, banana-processor, lemon-processor).

I want to have one function that has an object and a processor as input and starts a function in the processor given the object.

Something like this, obviously it doesn't work because the process function is not defined for the type Object.

```
private void doStuff (Object item, Object processor){
    processor.process(item);
}
```

Is there any better way to do that other than writing one function for each processor-item pair?

Comment: You can use 1. generics, 2. a map from Class to Processor, 3. factory pattern, 4. strategy pattern, and probably a bunch more. Choose your poison. Depending on your choice you need to rewrite or entirely replace your `doStuff` method. Be clear what result you want, not how to solve a specific detail on the road to your solution.

Comment: I would also add inheritance and polimorphism. For your specific task you can create an abstract class fruit and fruit processor and implement specific logic for each inherited class

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using generics

Create a superclass of your items (i.e. Fruit) and make those items extend this class, then edit the Processor class to accept generics:

```
public class Processor<T extends Fruit>{
  public void process(T item){
    //do your stuff here, may be check if item is instance of any fruit  you need
  }
}
```

In this way you just instance a new Processor of the type you need (i.e. `new Processor<Apple>`) and call the `process(T item)` method.